# MessageBox on Form Closing

Tags: c#, formclosing

I'm use this code for question before closing the application, but it is not working correctly.
My code is as below.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult dlgresult = MessageBox.Show("Exit or no?",
                               "My First Application",
                               MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                               MessageBoxIcon.Information);
   if (dlgresult == DialogResult.No)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;

   }
   else
   {
     Application.Exit();
   }
}
```

Comment: after responding no it request again the question and closes equally

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly call `Application.Exit()` since you are in the `FormClosing` event which means the Closing request has been triggered(e.g. click on the cross at the form button, `this.Close()`). You just need to intercept the closing request and indicate `e.Cancel = true;`

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(MessageBox.Show("Exit or no?",
                       "My First Application",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.No) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```